# Setting environment variables in package.json scripts under Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, environment-variables, webpack

You can set environment variables in Windows with the "SET" command:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
```

And you can specify short scripts in a package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "buildDev": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack",
    "buildProd": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack",
}
```

These work perfectly except for one thing: the value of `NODE_ENV` when webpack begins executing my config file is `"development "` - note the trailing space.

This prevents my config file from detecting the correct environment (via `process.env.NODE_ENV`) and returning the appropriate configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it cross-platform by using [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env):

`"buildDev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack"`

Answer (score 9):

I managed to fix this by, funnily enough, removing the space:

```
"buildDev": "set NODE_ENV=development&& webpack"
```

which (to me at least) seems just wrong.  I expected this would have resulted in a syntax error and a `NODE_ENV` value of `development&&`, but it works perfectly - albeit being ugly.